# Calling object methods with promises and the 'this' context

Tags: javascript, bluebird

I understand that in Javascript objects, the `this` keyword is not defined by declaration, but by invocation. So I am wondering how we can avoid the following problem:

```
var testObject = function(){
    this.foo = "foo!";
};

testObject.prototype.sayFoo = function() {
    console.log(this.foo);
};

var test = new testObject();
test.sayFoo(); //Prints "!foo"

new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    resolve();
}).then(test.sayFoo); //Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'foo' of undefined
```

Is:

```
new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    resolve();
}).then(function(){
    test.sayFoo();
});
```

the only solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can use the [`bind` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) as well:

```
Promise.resolve().then(test.sayFoo.bind(test));
```

See also [How to access the correct `this` context inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/1048572) for the generic problem.

However, [Bluebird does offer](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#binddynamic-thisarg---promise) an extra way to call the method:

```
Promise.resolve().bind(test).then(test.sayFoo);
```